# Vscode keeps inserting html tags into javascript when i type

Tags: visual-studio-code

Whenever i type a `/` or a `>` character, vscode automatically inserts a `</T>` into the file i'm working on, that has a recognized language `JavaScript`. The snippet is inserted as soon as the key is pressed, i get no option of rejecting this insert.

The change seems to be in recent versions, i can't remember this happening before with the same config.

Tried to remove all autosuggestions from settings:

```
  "emmet.excludeLanguages": ["markdown", "javascript"],
  "emmet.showExpandedAbbreviation": "never",
  "emmet.showAbbreviationSuggestions": false,
  "emmet.showSuggestionsAsSnippets": false,
  "emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab": false,
  "emmet.includeLanguages": {},
  "editor.suggestOnTriggerCharacters": false,
  "editor.acceptSuggestionOnCommitCharacter": false,
  "editor.quickSuggestions": {
    "other": false,
    "comments": false,
    "strings": false
  }
```

But it keeps happening and drivers me crazy. Happens on both windows and linux, 1.32.3 and 1.33.0-insider

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer, `javascript.autoClosingTags` seems to cause this with javascript code that has flowtype annotations. Setting to false fixed the issues.

Generics like `type Props<T> = {...}` leaves the editor expecting and suggesting a matching closing tag that happens each time you start typing a e.g. a comment `//` or an arrow function `=>`

Comment: If you're using flow, consider [installing the flow extension and disabling the builtin js one](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/javascript#_can-i-use-other-javascript-tools-like-flow)